# What could cause duplicates of a unique field when paging the results of a solr query?

Tags: solr

I'm moving a solr 1.3 installation from an outdated server to a new server.  Unfortunately the client can't upgrade because they can't reindex.

The new installation is working well, except that with a query that sorts on a particular field when paged returns a duplicate record for every page.  The same query run against the old server (both are using the same index data) doesn't do this.

The query is:

```
http://{solr_host}:8080/surveys_solr_search_prod/select
    ?indent=on&version=2.2
    &q=survey_resource_id%3A1304129+AND+company_id%3A51&fq=
    &start=0
    &rows=200"\
    &fl=*%2Cscore&qt=standard&wt=standard&explainOther=&hl.fl=
    &sort=survey_user_date_added%20asc"
```

both are running on tomcat6.  The old server is running IBM jvm 1.5 the new one is runing openjdk 7.

The schema is located [here](http://pastebin.com/pq8i5dR4).

Observations:

- If the sort is removed, the duplicate doesn't show up in multiple calls with different 'start' values.
- If the sort is changed to sort on another field (suid) the duplicate doesn't show up.
- The problem query is sorting on a date field & the problem result has a date that should put it at the end of the results, but it's showing up in the first page and each page thereafter.  Problem date: 2015-05-07T20:49:08.5Z, Next most recent on first page: 2009-01-12T00:09:59.5Z.  First date on second page: 2009-01-12T00:10:07.5Z

Any ideas?